# How should I write this function to return a pointer?

Tags: go, pointers

Assuming we have the following structures:

```golang
type BuyerData struct {
    id int
    balance float64
}
type AgentData struct {
    id int
    buyerData BuyerData
}
type GlobalData struct {
   agents map[int]AgentData
}
```

if I wanted to define a "insert equivalent of Java's class method" for `GlobalData` to return  a pointer to it's value `buyerData` on a given id, which would be a method with the following signature:

```golang
func (globalData *GlobalData) getBuyerData(id int) *BuyerData
```

What would be written inside it? I'm having troubles because it's giving all sorts of errors like `cannot take the address of`, `invalid indirect of` or `does not support indexing`...

---

This is what I currently have that does not generate any compiler exception:

```golang
func (globalData *GlobalData) getBuyerData(id int) *BuyerData {
    var agents *map[int]AgentData = &(globalData.agents)
    var agentData AgentData = (*agents)[id]
    return &(agentData.buyerData)
}
```

But I, honestly, don't know what I'm doing or if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: What are you wanting callers to be able to do with the pointer they receive?

Comment: What is `BuyerCustomData`?   It's not shown above and so this is not a complete listing!  `AgentData` has no `buyerCustomData` field.  Likewise `AgentsGlobalData`...

Comment: @Crowman I'm not sure since pointers aren't my thing at all... but I understand using them would be useful for a better memory management. Callers should be able to read and/or write. Suppose there's a global AgentsGlobalData variable.

Comment: @loko: You won't be able to write unless the type of the map value is itself a pointer, which it isn't. You can't (and wouldn't want to) get some kind of pointer into the map's internals. Even if the map value was a pointer, someone else could update the map for that key at any time thereby changing the address, so when updating you'd never be sure whether you were pointing at the right thing. If you want people to be able to write to the map, don't attempt to do it with pointers like this.

Comment: welll you /can/ get a pointer into into the map's internals technically.  but let's just pretend you can't ;)  Go is almost infinitely abuse-able.

Comment: @Crowman do you mean that `GlobalData.agents` should be `*map[int]AgentData` instead in order to prevent it's values address modification? Also, what would be the correct function signature in that case, if true?

Comment: @loko: No, I mean that `map[int]AgentData` should be `map[int]*AgentData`, but again, this is not a safe or reliable way to modify the contents of the map.

Comment: "I understand using them would be useful for a better memory management" no. Using pointers avoids a copy, but forces a heap allocation, so it's different, but not necessarily better. Use pointers when you need pointer semantics, and use values otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you'd just like to return a pointer to the value in the map in a AgentData struct indexed by the argument of the function, you likely mean to say:

```
func (agentsGlobalData *AgentData) getBuyerData(id int) (*BuyerData, bool) {
    buyer, has := agentsGlobalData.agents[id]
    return &buyer, has
}
```

You might also consider storing pointers to `AgentData` in that map instead, making your struct:

```
type GlobalData struct {
   agents map[int]*AgentData
}
```

But you haven't told us enough about your use case to recommend one or the other, perhaps.

(You say callers should be able to "write" to a `BuyerData`, but there are not any public fields in that struct...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to say something like this:

```golang
func (globalData *GlobalData) GetBuyerData(id int) *BuyerData {
  if agent, found := globalData.Agents[id]; found {
    return &agent.BuyerData
  }
  return nil
}
```

See it here: https://play.golang.org/p/lwXn4D1mr3J